# How Can I Find All Workflows Using a Custom Workflow Step

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a custom workflow step registered into Dynamics 365 CE. How can I find all workflows that contain that workflow step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A code-free way is

1. Navigate to Settings > Customizations
2. Click on "Customize the System"
3. Expand `Plugin Assemblies`
4. Select the assembly that contains your custom workflow step
5. Select the custom workflow step (i.e. check the box)
6. Click `Show Dependencies`

[image: Custom Workflow Step Dependencies]

Answer (score 0):

Credit to this post: https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/366932/find-a-specific-step-in-workflow

The gist of the answer is to write FetchXML to examine the `xaml` attribute of the `workflow` entity.

E.g. looking for the plugin `Example.WorkflowStep`

```xml
<fetch distinct="true" >
  <entity name="workflow" >
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="primaryentity" />
    <attribute name="statecode" />
    <attribute name="workflowid" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <attribute name="type" />
    <attribute name="owningbusinessunit" />
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="category" />
    <attribute name="xaml" />
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="type" operator="eq" value="1" />
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
      <filter type="and" >
        <condition attribute="rendererobjecttypecode" operator="null" />
        <condition attribute="xaml" operator="like" value="%Example.WorkflowStep%" />
      </filter>
    </filter>
    <order attribute="primaryentity" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```